# nslookup not properly picking up domains in list in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter, nslookup

In a Jupyter Notebook, I have a domain list like the following

```
domain_list=['google.com','example.com','thisisnotaworkingdomain12344321.com']
```

I intend to pass this list through a loop to check and if each domain is live by running a quick NSLookup. However, when I enter the following code:

```
for i in range(len(domain_list)):
! nslookup domain_list[i]
```

I am returned the following:

```
    Server:  dsldevice6.attlocal.net
Address:  redacted

*** dsldevice6.attlocal.net can't find domain_list[i]: Non-existent domain

Server:  dsldevice6.attlocal.net
Address:  redacted

*** dsldevice6.attlocal.net can't find domain_list[i]: Non-existent domain

Server:  dsldevice6.attlocal.net
Address:  redacted

*** dsldevice6.attlocal.net can't find domain_list[i]: Non-existent domain
```

So it is obviously doing an nslookup for "domain_list[i]", not for the ith item in the domain list. Is there a solution that anyone could provide? I cannot identify a quick workaround.

Comment: The "!" thing is a Jupyter hack, and variables can't be referenced by name.  Why not just do it the RIGHT way, by using `subprocess.call`?

Comment: What do you mean by "live"?  `nslookup` can tell you if the domain is registered in DNS.  It says nothing about whether a server is answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you need to do with the output, this is the kind of thing you need:

```
import subprocess

for domain in domain_list:
    subprocess.call( ['nslookup', domain] )
```

Even easier is:

```
import socket

for domain in domain_list:
    print( socket.gethostbyname( domain ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import dns.resolver

for i in domain_list:

    try:
        result=dns.resolver.resolve(i,'NS')
    except TypeError:
        domain_list.remove(i)
```

This seems like a solid band-aid fix to the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).